# Tensorflow Hub Model download causes PermissionDeniedError in WSL

Tags: python-3.x, linux, tensorflow2.0, windows-subsystem-for-linux, tensorflow-hub

In my project, the three following paths refer to the same location:

```
os.environ["TFHUB_CACHE_DIR"] = "~/my_repos/my_project/data/tfhub_cache/"
os.environ["TFHUB_CACHE_DIR"] = os.path.normpath("./data/tfhub_cache/")
os.environ["TFHUB_CACHE_DIR"] = os.path.normpath(os.path.dirname(__file__) + "../data/tfhub_cache/")
```

and they are used by the following code:

```
import tensorflow_hub as hub
embed = hub.load("https://tfhub.dev/google/universal-sentence-encoder/3")
```

However, the first one works correctly, while the other two, cause the following error:

```
Downloading pre-trained embeddings from tensorflow hub...
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/my_username/.pyenv/versions/3.7.5/lib/python3.7/runpy.py", line 193, in _run_module_as_main
    "__main__", mod_spec)
  File "/home/my_username/.pyenv/versions/3.7.5/lib/python3.7/runpy.py", line 85, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "/home/my_username/my_repos/my_project/my_script.py", line 229, in <module>
    embed = hub.load("https://tfhub.dev/google/universal-sentence-encoder/3")
  File "/home/my_username/.local/share/virtualenvs/my_project-fkeckdfE/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow_hub/module_v2.py", line 90, in load
    module_path = resolve(handle)
  File "/home/my_username/.local/share/virtualenvs/my_project-fkeckdfE/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow_hub/module_v2.py", line 52, in resolve
    return registry.resolver(handle)
  File "/home/my_username/.local/share/virtualenvs/my_project-fkeckdfE/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow_hub/registry.py", line 42, in __call__
    return impl(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/my_username/.local/share/virtualenvs/my_project-fkeckdfE/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow_hub/compressed_module_resolver.py", line 88, in __call__
    self._lock_file_timeout_sec())
  File "/home/my_username/.local/share/virtualenvs/my_project-fkeckdfE/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow_hub/resolver.py", line 414, in atomic_download
    tf_v1.gfile.Rename(tmp_dir, module_dir)
  File "/home/my_username/.local/share/virtualenvs/my_project-fkeckdfE/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/lib/io/file_io.py", line 504, in rename
    rename_v2(oldname, newname, overwrite)
  File "/home/my_username/.local/share/virtualenvs/my_project-fkeckdfE/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/lib/io/file_io.py", line 521, in rename_v2
    compat.as_bytes(src), compat.as_bytes(dst), overwrite)
tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.PermissionDeniedError: /home/my_username/my_repos/my_project/data/tfhub_cache/42480c3c7f42bf87d36d4c58fc4374b08dae2909.dcfe9db0c4ea456b9d3c97359f57ec1a.tmp; Permission denied
```

Any ideas what is causing this? (I have already `chmod -R 777` on the directory!)

The script is ran using `pipenv` ie. `pipenv run python -m scripts.my_script`

Ideally, I would like the second one to work, so that other devs who have their repo in different locations are still able to just run the script.

Comment: I'm unable to repro your issue using Ubuntu 18.0.4 via WSL either with or without pipenv. If this is still an issue, can you provide more details, like which version of WSL, Python, TF, and Hub you are using?